# Does this DEFINE a CFT?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, conformal-field-theory, scaling

I have a discrete correlated system defined on a squared grid in $d=2$, all euclidean. I have a random field at each point given by a local function of Grassmann variables (I wouldn't say fermions because I don't have spins or any other physical property). I was able to compute ALL the $n$-point functions (i.e., joint-moments) explicitly, and I also have their explicit form when I take the continuum limit (which is, taking the grid separation to $0$). Moreover, I was able to prove that those limiting $n$-point functions are all covariant under a conformal mapping, with scale dimension $2$.

Question: Is it safe to assert that this (uniquely maybe?) defines a CFT in $d=2$?

Comment: Not necessarily. Are the 4 (and higher) point functions crossing symmetric?

Comment: That’s a good question. I need to check it out. I can’t tell you right off the bat because I’m rusty with CFT and my research is in probability theory, although we are observing connections with CFT. Now, suppose I do have crossing symmetry, then the answer is yes? And if I don’t, the answer is no?

Comment: @almostsurely a CFT has an state-operator map which relates quasi-primary operators and their descendants to states. One of the main consequences of the state-operator map is the Operator Product Expansion (OPE). The OPE says that a product of two operators at points $x$ and $y$ can be expanded in a series in powers of $|x-y|$ which is valid until you find another operator insertion. The associativity of the OPE reflects in the crossing symmetry of the operators. So, yes, a CFT must have crossing symmetric correlators. Indeed this is the basic input of the conformal bootstrap.